# Custom comment type pagination in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a custom comment type 'blog'. Changing the settings under "Settings > Discussion Settings > Break comments into pages..." has no impact on the number of comments displayed on the page.

Also, the following doesn't seem to work for custom comment types.

```
paginate_comments_links()
```

How can set up pagination on custom comments in WordPress?

Comment: You need to adjust your query to look for a custom post type, it will not do it by default.

Comment: My custom comments are showing on the page so my query is working. The problem is with the pagination. I have 100s of comments on the page so would like to break them down into say 20 comments per page